# Javascript rich text editor with client side spell checking

Tags: tinymce, ckeditor, spell-checking, rich-text-editor, hunspell

I am currently investigating implementing a rich text editor with spell-checking capabilities (hopefully out-of-the-box).

I have looked at quite a few other questions regarding spell checking and most of them requires a server-based (ajax) solution (which is not very performant when implementing "check as you type").

A while back, I was working on a RichTextEditor in Flex and was able to implement [squiggly](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/squiggly/) which is client side checking and very fast.

I am currently considering TinyMCE and CKEditor at the moment, but couldn't find any information as to whether they can integrate hunspell dictionaries for client side checking.

Have any of you successfully integrated any client side spell checking with those 2 rich text editors? The dictionaries don't necessary have to be hunspell, but it is prefered.

Comment: Certain combinations of OS/browser take care of spell check, you know...

Comment: I know HTML5 allows for the `spellcheck` attribute, but there are people on older browsers or browsers without spellcheck capabilities.

Comment: Were you able to find any solution to your problem? I'm looking for the same. A spellchecker for TinyMce.

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking at current cross browser spell checking abilities and whether they work with HTML Editors like CKEditor.  I did find in the CKEditor documentation ([CKEditor Docs](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.disableNativeSpellChecker))

that you can disable/enable the native spellchecker and that when it is enabled, you can get access to the native browser spell check menu by holding the Ctrl key down and right-clicking on the misspelled word(squiggle).  FYI IE10 will soon be out and will also contain a native spell checker in the browser with support for the HTML5 spellcheck and editablecontent tags.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox supports hunspell dictionaries (so called AddOns). All you need to do to make it work is to use ther tinymce init parameter `gecko_spellcheck: true,` . For Internet explorer and other browsers you might need to use a server-based approach.

Comment: I am trying to make this a client based solution. I have tried many server based solution and they all seem to be quite slow (especially since I want to implement check as you type). There is also the possiblity that the application will be used offline, hence a preference for a client-based solution.

Comment: i have no cross-browser solution to offer

Comment: @Thariama: Can you have a look at the similar case [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271142/best-third-party-spellchecker-to-be-used-in-tinymce)? Is implementing tiny's spellchecker plugin in Perl a time-taking job or piece of cake?